# What event fires after .Load in Codefluent?

Tags: codefluent

I want to store an initial value when an object is loaded in a private property. If I change the value later on I want to be able to compare the initial and the current value. I can't find a suitable event for capturing the initial value. Should be just after loading the object... OnAfterCreate does not do the trick..

I could propably also use the PropertyChanged event but I am not sure how to implement it..

Comment: OnAfterReadRecord? https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/EventRules_LifecycleMethodEvents.html

Comment: ModelHistory? https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/BOM_EVT_EN_PropertyChanged.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was OnAfterReadRecord indeed. Thanks Simon!

> protected void OnAfterReadRecord(System.Data.IDataReader reader,
>   CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentReloadOptions options)
>           {
>               _initialActive = CodeFluentPersistence.GetReaderValue(reader, "CwObject_Active",
>   ((bool)(false)));
>           }